# Nodejs after redirection comes a new request with wrong URL

Tags: php, node.js, amazon-ec2, bitnami

I have an old website build with PHP. I have created a new application using Nodejs now. I want to redirect all the old URLs to the new website.

> **OLD Website URL looks like**
> xyz.com/index.php/articles/display_article/abcCategory/article-slug
>
> **NEW Website URL looks like**
> xyz.com/articles/abcCategory/article-slug/articleId

Now Using NODE I am redirecting old URL to the new URL by:

```
app.all('*', function(req, res, next){
  if (req.url.includes('index.php')) {
    myService.getNewURL(req.url).then(function(err, newUrl) {
       console.log('reditrecting to new url');
       res.redirect(301, newUrl);
    });
  } else {
    next();
  }
});
```

**Now it consoles it is redirecting to the new URL but the node server gets another request with req.url as /index.php/articles/display_article/abcCategory/xyz.com/articles/abcCategory/article-slug/articleId**

and it does not redirect properly. When I test this on the local server, it is working all good but not on the server.

I am using AWS server for this.

Can you please help if there is anything that needs to be done on the Apache side or make changes in the nodejs code.

Comment: It sounds like the relevant code would be whatever `myService.getNewURL()` does.  Logging its input and output in dev and prod should make the problem apparent.

Comment: getNewURL() function calls the db and get the article id based on the articleSlug in the req.url and creates the new URL using string concat function and returns newURL. the result is same in dev and prod.

Comment: when res.redirect is called to the new correct URL, there comes a new api request with the wrong req.url which does not in dev.. but prod. and  that is the issue..i assume

Comment: How did you fix this ? When i call res.redirect with an url, i'm redirect to the wrong url (redirected to the current domain instead of my newdomain)